# is "do I understand this right" an idiomatic expression?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I am learning this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial).

I made this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3253943/673047) to check my understanding.

after writing my understanding, I put this expression "do I understand this right" at the end of the post.

is "do I understand this right" an idiomatic expression?

or

"am I understanding right" is more idiomatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"do I understand this right" is fine.

"am I understanding right" should be: "am I understanding THIS right", and is also absolutely fine; there is very little difference between the two. I expect some commentators will prefer one over the other, but probably in equal measure.

Don't forget to use capital letters at the start of all your sentences.